Why does getopt() not work when option and argument are separate?
I am trying to pass arguments to my process: (Product (int), Timestamp (std::string), LPN (std::string), Class (int) and State (int)).
I want to execute my process like this:
AccountCreationSimulator_Exe -p 6 -t 0 -l ABC1234 -c 2 -n 1.

But it does not work with spaces. To make it work, I have to type this:
AccountCreationSimulator_Exe -p6 -t0 -lABC1234 -c2 -n1

Is there any way to let you to type a space between the argument and the value?
Here the code that calls getopt():
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char*  argv[])
{
    int m_nProduct = 0;
    std::string m_strTimestamp;
    std::string m_strLpn;
    int m_nVehClass = 0;
    int m_nLpnState = 0;

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:t:l:c:n:")) != -1) {
        try {
            switch (opt) {
                case 'p':
                    m_nProduct = std::stoi(optarg);
                    break;
                case 't':
                    m_strTimestamp = optarg;
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    m_strLpn = optarg;
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    m_nVehClass = std::stoi(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    m_nLpnState = std::stoi(optarg);
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "Unknown option: " << opt << std::endl;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
            std::cerr << "Invalid argument for option: " << opt << " - " << optarg << '\n';
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
            std::cerr << "Out of range argument for option: " << opt << " - " << optarg << '\n';
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "m_nProduct = " << m_nProduct << '\n'
              << "m_strTimestamp = " << m_strTimestamp << '\n'
              << "m_strLpn = " << m_strLpn << '\n'
              << "m_nVehClass = " << m_nVehClass << '\n'
              << "m_nLpnState = " << m_nLpnState << '\n';
}

Also, I put some different invocations of the process if someone find them useful. (I haven't used -p in these executions to avoid the process continuing).
AccountCreationSimulator_Exe -t0 -lABC1234 -c2 -n1
2024/06/18 08:36:06.638 2024/06/18 08:36:06.639 Account Creation Simulator
The product argument is mandatory.
P - -1 || T - 0 || L - ABC1234 || C - 2 || N - 1

AccountCreationSimulator_Exe -t "0" -l "ABC1234" -c 2
2024/06/18 08:37:33.473 2024/06/18 08:37:33.473 Account Creation Simulator
The product argument is mandatory.
P - -1 || T - -l || L -  || C - 0 || N - 1

AccountCreationSimulator_Exe -t "0" -l "ABC1234" -c 2 -n 1
2024/06/18 08:38:22.206 2024/06/18 08:38:22.206 Account Creation Simulator
Invalid argument for option: 99 - -n
AccountCreationSimulator_Exe - EXCEPTION: stoi

I have tried to change the type of the variables.
Also it works if the arguments are typed this way -l\\ ABC1234.
I have tried with double quotes and single quotes.

That's not the output of code presented, there is no std::cout << '\n' << "optarg: " << optarg << '\n';visible in output.

I've edited so that your code is a [mcve] that can be compiled and run by anyone.  You might want to update your program output to reflect what you get (rather than what I get).

Cannot duplicate.

It seems to work just fine if I provide the arguments programatically. But I also checked locally in my bash and executing the program ./test -t     6 -l     WHATEVER with any amount of spaces seems to work fine.
